# git command to compare current working directory and another commit

Tags: git, git-diff

I have a modified file on my current working directory called `file.txt`. I want to compare it with a version of it on *debug* branch. The following command does not work:

```
git diff file.txt debug:file.txt
```

fatal: Path 'file.txt' exists on disk, but not in 'debug'

How can I compare them? Do I have to commit first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following command to compare `file.txt` from current branch to `debug` branch:

```
git diff debug file.txt
```